# Code can not end looping, using cv2.imwrite() in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm running this basic code in python. It has *no loops* but it runs endelessly, I had the command to save an image, that i turned from colored to grayscaled.

So before the cv2.waitKey(0) the code works and I can save the first image, after cv2.waitKey(0) it reads nothing, because, I think, it continues looping.

this is the very basic code:

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(dir_path)

cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)

img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/carlo/PycharmProjects/OpenCV_AnaConda/opencv/samples/data/lena.jpg",0)      

print(img)

cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/carlo/PycharmProjects/OpenCV_lavendetta/lena_1.jpg', img)
print("it runs the code until here")

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/carlo/PycharmProjects/OpenCV_lavendetta/lena_2.jpg', img)
print("the code ends")
```

How can I solve this? Thank You

Comment: The `waitkey` function is for waiting for a key-press from the user. Are you pressing a key?

Comment: Are you pressing a key? "waitKey(0) will display the window infinitely until any keypress" Also does the image appear then never disappear or does it disappear and then nothing else happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention looping, but there are no loops in your code. `cv2.waitKey(0)` is going to wait infinitely for user input. [From the docs:](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey)

> The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when delay <= 0 ) or for delay milliseconds, when it is positive.

`waitKey(0)` is waiting for a key to be pressed, so you press a key and the program should continue. If you want it to only wait for a limited amount of time, enter the number of milliseconds you want to have it appear for.

For example: to have it only appear for 3 seconds and then continue program execution do `cv2.waitkey(3000)`.